# Syntax error while upgrading Liferay 6.0.5 to 6.1.0

Tags: liferay, liferay-6, liferay-theme

I am trying to upgrading Liferay 6.0.5 to 6.1.0. For this I follow the steps in the sites https://www.liferay.com/documentation/liferay-portal/6.1/user-guide/-/ai/upgrading-lifer-5.  But during the upgradation process I got the following error.

```
10:48:21,489 INFO  [DialectDetector:80] Determine dialect for PostgreSQL 9
10:48:21,522 INFO  [DialectDetector:145] Found dialect org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
Starting Liferay Portal Community Edition 6.1.0 CE (Paton / Build 6100 / January 6, 2012)
10:48:44,349 INFO  [BaseDB:406] Database supports case sensitive queries
10:48:44,530 INFO  [UpgradeProcess:205] Upgrading com.liferay.portal.upgrade.UpgradeProcess_6_0_6
10:48:44,532 INFO  [UpgradeProcess:205] Upgrading com.liferay.portal.upgrade.v6_0_6.UpgradeSchema
10:48:44,599 INFO  [UpgradeProcess:205] Upgrading com.liferay.portal.upgrade.v6_0_6.UpgradeRSS
10:48:45,006 INFO  [UpgradeProcess:205] Upgrading com.liferay.portal.upgrade.UpgradeProcess_6_1_0
10:48:45,007 INFO  [UpgradeProcess:205] Upgrading com.liferay.portal.upgrade.v6_1_0.UpgradeSchema
10:49:07,783 INFO  [UpgradeProcess:205] Upgrading com.liferay.portal.upgrade.v6_1_0.UpgradeUserName
10:49:08,272 INFO  [UpgradeProcess:205] Upgrading com.liferay.portal.upgrade.v6_1_0.UpgradeAdminPortlets
10:49:21,512 INFO  [UpgradeProcess:205] Upgrading com.liferay.portal.upgrade.v6_1_0.UpgradeBlogs
10:49:21,529 INFO  [UpgradeProcess:205] Upgrading com.liferay.portal.upgrade.v6_1_0.UpgradeCamelCasePortletPreferences
10:53:16,032 INFO  [UpgradeProcess:205] Upgrading com.liferay.portal.upgrade.v6_1_0.UpgradeCountry
10:53:16,264 INFO  [UpgradeProcess:205] Upgrading com.liferay.portal.upgrade.v6_1_0.UpgradeDocumentLibrary
11:00:46,866 INFO  [UpgradeProcess:205] Upgrading com.liferay.portal.upgrade.v6_1_0.UpgradeExpando
11:00:46,872 INFO  [UpgradeProcess:205] Upgrading com.liferay.portal.upgrade.v6_1_0.UpgradeGroup
11:00:51,024 ERROR [MainServlet:198] com.liferay.portal.kernel.events.ActionException: com.liferay.portal.kernel.upgrade.UpgradeException: com.liferay.portal.kernel.upgrade.UpgradeException: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: syntax error at or near "s"
  Position: 81
com.liferay.portal.kernel.events.ActionException: com.liferay.portal.kernel.upgrade.UpgradeException: com.liferay.portal.kernel.upgrade.UpgradeException: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: syntax error at or near "s"
  Position: 81
    at com.liferay.portal.events.StartupAction.run(StartupAction.java:58)
    at com.liferay.portal.servlet.MainServlet.processStartupEvents(MainServlet.java:1267)
    at com.liferay.portal.servlet.MainServlet.init(MainServlet.java:195)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1266)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1185)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1080)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:5001)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5289)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:866)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:842)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:615)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:649)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDescriptor.run(HostConfig.java:1581)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1146)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679)
Caused by: com.liferay.portal.kernel.upgrade.UpgradeException: com.liferay.portal.kernel.upgrade.UpgradeException: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: syntax error at or near "s"
  Position: 81
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.upgrade.UpgradeProcess.upgrade(UpgradeProcess.java:211)
    at com.liferay.portal.upgrade.UpgradeProcessUtil._upgradeProcess(UpgradeProcessUtil.java:93)
    at com.liferay.portal.upgrade.UpgradeProcessUtil.upgradeProcess(UpgradeProcessUtil.java:46)
    at com.liferay.portal.events.StartupHelper.upgradeProcess(StartupHelper.java:81)
    at com.liferay.portal.events.StartupHelperUtil.upgradeProcess(StartupHelperUtil.java:40)
    at com.liferay.portal.tools.DBUpgrader.upgrade(DBUpgrader.java:119)
    at com.liferay.portal.events.StartupAction.doRun(StartupAction.java:144)
    at com.liferay.portal.events.StartupAction.run(StartupAction.java:52)
    ... 20 more
Caused by: com.liferay.portal.kernel.upgrade.UpgradeException: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: syntax error at or near "s"
  Position: 81
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.upgrade.UpgradeProcess.upgrade(UpgradeProcess.java:211)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.upgrade.UpgradeProcess.upgrade(UpgradeProcess.java:225)
    at com.liferay.portal.upgrade.UpgradeProcess_6_1_0.doUpgrade(UpgradeProcess_6_1_0.java:66)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.upgrade.UpgradeProcess.upgrade(UpgradeProcess.java:208)
    ... 27 more
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: syntax error at or near "s"
  Position: 81
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2103)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:1836)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:257)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.execute(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:512)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.executeWithFlags(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:374)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.executeUpdate(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:302)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyStatement.executeUpdate(NewProxyStatement.java:64)
    at com.liferay.portal.dao.db.BaseDB.runSQL(BaseDB.java:237)
    at com.liferay.portal.dao.db.BaseDB.runSQL(BaseDB.java:204)
    at com.liferay.portal.dao.db.BaseDB.runSQL(BaseDB.java:191)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.upgrade.UpgradeProcess.runSQL(UpgradeProcess.java:115)
    at com.liferay.portal.upgrade.v6_1_0.UpgradeGroup.updateName(UpgradeGroup.java:86)
    at com.liferay.portal.upgrade.v6_1_0.UpgradeGroup.doUpgrade(UpgradeGroup.java:51)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.upgrade.UpgradeProcess.upgrade(UpgradeProcess.java:208)
    ... 30 more
```

I am using Postgres 9.4 and the error shown as syntax error . I am unable to resolve the error. Please help me.

Comment: No answer unfortunately, but Liferay apparently doesn't care about Postgres users. With every new version I always see very basic syntax errors in Liferay when running against Postgres (that are admittedly fixed in later versions, but they don't seem to test on Postgres)

Comment: But my old version Liferay 6.0.5 is in Postgresql and running fine. So if I want to use old data in Liferay 6.1.0, what I had to do . Any Idea ?

Comment: Why are you using 6.1.0 if there is a 6.1.2 available? Maybe the bug was fixed in the updated release?

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade routines get fixed with newer minor releases, same with this: Please try the last available 6.1 update release (which, by the way, won't receive any future upgrades - my recommendation is to continue to update to 6.2 GA4).

If the problem still persists when upgrading to 6.1.2, you might want to try the direct update to 6.2 without stopping at 6.1.x and see if that update process fixes your problem.

Comment: Thanks a lot to all. I will try it with said version.